# # in url in amsrefs

Tags: symbols, amsrefs

I want to include a reference to a web page using amsrefs and the webpage bibliography entry type. The url has a # in it. A error message is issued, but after entering scroll mode, it is typeset correctly. Is there a way to avoid the error message?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
Main text
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{web}{webpage}{
accessdate={2015-3-10},
title={My web page},
url={http://www.mywebpage/#name},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following message:

```
./amsrefs.tex:18: Illegal parameter number in definition of \star@a.
<to be read again> 
n
l.14    url={http://www.mywebpage/#name}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be considered a bug; maybe using the `url` package (which is also loaded by `hyperref`) might solve it.

For this particular case you can add a trick:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} % optional

\AtBeginEnvironment{biblist}{\catcode`\#=12 }

\begin{document}
Main text
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{web}{webpage}{
accessdate={2015-3-10},
title={My web page},
url={http://www.mywebpage/#name},
}
\bib{google}{webpage}{
accessdate={2015-3-10},
title={My web page},
url={http://www.google.com/#},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second link is effective if `hyperref` is used.

Comment: It seems that the `url` package doesn't solve this.

Comment: @karlkoeller No, the catcode setting is still necessary; what I was suggesting is that the `amsrefs` package might use the `url` package facilities for URLs in references.